# refreshing a jtable without showing result more than one time

Tags: java, button, jtable, refresh

I have a jtable that is refreshed by clicking a button. But every time I click the refresh buttom the same result is shown again.

*For exemple the first time I click on refresh the displayed result on jtable is:

name

surname

*the second time I click on refresh the result is:

name

surname

name

surname

the same result is duplicated. 
how should I get the result for one time even I click the refresh button more than once?

the class containing the refresh button :ModalityWorklist.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Dell
 */



public class ModalityWorklist extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private String[] args;
   public static File file;
    public static String Name;
    public static String id;
    public static Object[] row;

    /**
     * Creates new form ModalityWorklist
     */
    public ModalityWorklist(){
        initComponents();


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        modalityWorklist = new javax.swing.JTable();
        refresh = new javax.swing.JButton();
        ok = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        modalityWorklist.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Patient ID", "Patient Name"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        modalityWorklist.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                modalityWorklistMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(modalityWorklist);

        refresh.setText("refresh");
        refresh.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                refreshActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        ok.setText("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                okActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 451, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(refresh)))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(221, 221, 221)
                .addComponent(ok, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(refresh)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 16, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(ok)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void refreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        GetMwl_3.main(args);

    }                                       

    private void modalityWorklistMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                              
        if(evt.getClickCount()==2){
        int i = modalityWorklist.getSelectedRow();
        TableModel model =modalityWorklist.getModel();  
        id=model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        Name=model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
        selectedPatient.main(args,Name,id);
        }
    }                                             

    private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
     dispose();
    }                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ModalityWorklist.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ModalityWorklist.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ModalityWorklist.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ModalityWorklist.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                new ModalityWorklist().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    public static javax.swing.JTable modalityWorklist;
    private javax.swing.JButton ok;
    private javax.swing.JButton refresh;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

the class that retrieve the worklist: GetMwl_3.java

```
public class GetMwl_3 {
 private String[] args;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args/*,String aet, String host, Integer port*/) {
        new GetMwl_3(/*aet,host,port*/);
    }

    private static final int[] RETURN_KEYS = {
        Tag.AccessionNumber,
        Tag.ReferringPhysicianName,
        Tag.PatientName,
        Tag.PatientID,
        Tag.PatientBirthDate,
        Tag.PatientSex,
        Tag.PatientWeight,
        Tag.MedicalAlerts,
        Tag.Allergies,
        Tag.PregnancyStatus,
        Tag.StudyInstanceUID,
        Tag.RequestingPhysician,
        Tag.RequestingService,
        Tag.RequestedProcedureDescription,
        Tag.AdmissionID,
        Tag.SpecialNeeds,
        Tag.CurrentPatientLocation,
        Tag.PatientState,
        Tag.RequestedProcedureID,
        Tag.RequestedProcedurePriority,
        Tag.PatientTransportArrangements,
        Tag.PlacerOrderNumberImagingServiceRequest,
        Tag.FillerOrderNumberImagingServiceRequest,
        Tag.ConfidentialityConstraintOnPatientDataDescription,
    };

    private static final int[] SPS_RETURN_KEYS = {
        Tag.Modality,
        Tag.RequestedContrastAgent,
        Tag.ScheduledStationAETitle,
        Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate,
        Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartTime,
        Tag.ScheduledPerformingPhysicianName,
        Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepDescription,
        Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepID,
        Tag.ScheduledStationName,
        Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepLocation,
        Tag.PreMedication,
        Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStatus
    };

    private static final String[] LE_TS = {
        UID.ExplicitVRLittleEndian, 
        UID.ImplicitVRLittleEndian };

    private static final byte[] EXT_NEG_INFO_FUZZY_MATCHING = { 1, 1, 1 };

    private Device device;
    private final NetworkApplicationEntity remoteAE = new NetworkApplicationEntity();
    private final NetworkConnection remoteConn = new NetworkConnection();
     private final NetworkApplicationEntity ae = new NetworkApplicationEntity();
     private final NetworkConnection conn = new NetworkConnection();
     private final DicomObject keys = new BasicDicomObject();
     private final DicomObject spsKeys = new BasicDicomObject();
     private Association assoc;
     private int priority = 0;
     private int cancelAfter = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//ÐœÐ°ÐºÑ ÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡ÐµÑÑ‚Ð²Ð¾ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾Ðº

     private boolean fuzzySemanticPersonNameMatching;
    private Component emptyLabel;

    public GetMwl_3(/*String aet, String host, Integer port*/) {
        String name = "DCMMWL";
        device = new Device(name);
        NewThreadExecutor executor = new NewThreadExecutor(name);
        remoteAE.setInstalled(true);
        remoteAE.setAssociationAcceptor(true);
        remoteAE.setNetworkConnection(new NetworkConnection[] { remoteConn });

        device.setNetworkApplicationEntity(ae);
        device.setNetworkConnection(conn);
        ae.setNetworkConnection(conn);
        ae.setAssociationInitiator(true);
        ae.setAETitle(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < RETURN_KEYS.length; i++) {
            keys.putNull(RETURN_KEYS[i], null);
        }        
        keys.putNestedDicomObject(Tag.RequestedProcedureCodeSequence,
                new BasicDicomObject());
        keys.putNestedDicomObject(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepSequence, spsKeys);
        for (int i = 0; i < SPS_RETURN_KEYS.length; i++) {
            spsKeys.putNull(SPS_RETURN_KEYS[i], null);
        }
        spsKeys.putNestedDicomObject(Tag.ScheduledProtocolCodeSequence,
                new BasicDicomObject());

        /////////
       // remoteAE.setAETitle(aet);
       // remoteConn.setHostname(host);
       // remoteConn.setPort(port);
        remoteAE.setAETitle("DCM4CHEE");
        remoteConn.setHostname("localhost");
        remoteConn.setPort(11112);

       // addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.Modality, "CR");
        //addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.Modality, "CR");
//        addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate,"20131030");
//        addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartTime,"11111");

        setTransferSyntax(LE_TS);

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            assoc = ae.connect(remoteAE, executor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: Failed to establish association:");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(2);
        }

        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Connected to " + remoteAE + " in "
                + ((t2 - t1) / 1000F) + "s");

        try {
            List<DicomObject> result = query();
            long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Received " + result.size()
                    + " matching entries in " + ((t3 - t2) / 1000F) + "s");



            for(DicomObject dcm : result) {

                worklist.main(args, dcm.getString(Tag.PatientName), dcm.getString(Tag.PatientID));

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            assoc.release(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Released connection to " + remoteAE);
    }

    public void setTransferSyntax(String[] ts) {
        TransferCapability tc = new TransferCapability(
                UID.ModalityWorklistInformationModelFIND, ts,
                TransferCapability.SCU);
        if (fuzzySemanticPersonNameMatching)
            tc.setExtInfo(EXT_NEG_INFO_FUZZY_MATCHING);
        ae.setTransferCapability(new TransferCapability[]{tc});
    }

        public void addSpsMatchingKey(int tag, String value) {
        spsKeys.putString(tag, null, value);
    }

    public List<DicomObject> query() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        TransferCapability tc = assoc.getTransferCapabilityAsSCU(
                UID.ModalityWorklistInformationModelFIND);
        if (tc == null) {
            throw new NoPresentationContextException(
                    "Modality Worklist not supported by "
                    + remoteAE.getAETitle());
        }
        //System.out.println("Send Query Request:");
        //System.out.println(keys.toString());
        DimseRSP rsp = assoc.cfind(UID.ModalityWorklistInformationModelFIND,
                priority, keys, tc.getTransferSyntax()[0], cancelAfter);
        List<DicomObject> result = new ArrayList<DicomObject>();
        while (rsp.next()) {
            DicomObject cmd = rsp.getCommand();
            if (CommandUtils.isPending(cmd)) {
                DicomObject data = rsp.getDataset();
                result.add(data);
                //System.out.println("\nReceived Query Response #"
                      //  + result.size() + ":");
                //System.out.println(data.toString());
            }
        }
        return result;

    }



}
```

and this is the class that adds rows to the jtable :worklist.java

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Dell
 */

public class worklist extends ModalityWorklist{
     public worklist(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args,String Name,String ID) {

    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)modalityWorklist.getModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Patient ID","Patient Name"});
       row=new Object[2];
        row[0]=ID;
        row[1]=Name;
        model.addRow(row);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to delete the rows and display them again

```
int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
            for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                model.removeRow(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you are refreshing the table you are duplicating the items in your Model. Can you show us the code that you are executing when hitting refresh?

Your refresh button should be calling `fireTableDataChanged()` on the JTable instace. That should be all, if you updated the model, the table should be updated correctly.

Comment: Exactly. You're re-adding items. Either **a)** clean the JTable data before that 'refresh' **b)** initialize a new DataModel/TableModel **c)** Decouple refreshing and adding items **d)** as ejoncas stated, call the `fireTableDataChanged()` method. This would be the best way to go

Comment: I edited my question to add the code ,please can you explain more because I'm very new to java